# mySQL: extract data that is older then a specific year, month and day

Tags: mysql

i have a table, like this:

```
image (image_id, ..., published_date_year, published_date_month, published_date_day , is_listed)
```

I want to extract all images that have, at least, a published_date_year and that are older then the 2 of june 2006

I've manage to extract all images with a published_date_year that are <= 2006

```
SELECT i.published_date_year, i.published_date_month, i.published_date_day
FROM image i
WHERE i.published_date_year IS NOT NULL AND i.published_date_year <= 2006
```

If i add month and day to my query, it removes all data from other years, wich is not what i'm looking:

```
SELECT i.published_date_year, i.published_date_month, i.published_date_day
FROM image i
WHERE i.published_date_year IS NOT NULL AND i.published_date_year <= 2006 AND published_date_month <= 6 AND published_date_day <= 2
```

How to extract images with at least a year and that are older then the 2 of june 2006?

**EDIT**

An image can have a year, but not necessarily a month or a day.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the str_to_date function eg. as below

```
SELECT i.published_date_year, i.published_date_month, i.published_date_day
FROM image i
WHERE i.published_date_year IS NOT NULL 
AND str_to_date(concat(i.published_date_year,'/',i.published_date_month,'/',i.published_date_day),'%Y/%m/%d') <= str_to_date('2006/06/02','%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: this work ok, but, there are cases where a year exists but the month and the day are not specified. In those cases, i need to extract them also. I've edited my question so it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select * from (
    SELECT image_id, published_date_year, published_date_month, published_date_day, 
        concat(published_date_year, '-', lpad(ifnull(published_date_month,0),2,'0'), '-', lpad(ifnull(published_date_month,0),2,'0')) as published_date
    FROM image
    where published_date_year is not null) as q
where q.published_date <= '2006-06-02';
```

Updated for your updated request. The ifnull() should work with narendra's solution too, like this:

```
SELECT i.published_date_year, i.published_date_month, i.published_date_day
FROM image i
WHERE i.published_date_year IS NOT NULL 
AND str_to_date(concat(i.published_date_year,'/',ifnull(i.published_date_month,0),'/',ifnull(i.published_date_day,0)),'%Y/%m/%d') <= str_to_date('2006/06/02','%Y/%m/%d');
```